# Plotting Pandas crosstab without margins values

Tags: python, pandas

I created a crosstable df with margins and I would like to plot it without the Total row and colum.

My df :

| categ | f | m | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20 | 209356 | 415459 |
| 1 | 11 | 112270 | 227169 |
| 2 | 17283 | 19200 | 36483 |
| Total | 338285 | 340826 | 679111 |

Then df.plot(kind='bar') I got the 3 categories but also the Total on the X axis but also the total column in my bars

How can i do to remove the margins when plotting ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Show your code or `margins=False`.

Comment: df= pd.crosstab(index=base['categ'], columns=base['sex'], values=base['price'], aggfunc='count', margins=True,margins_name="Total").copy()

and df.plot(kind='bar')

Comment: You can remove `margisn=True, margins_name="Total"`.

Comment: ok so there is no chance to plot without creating a new dataframe. Because I need the crosstab with margins and in addition I need a chart from this table

Comment: maybe you want `df.loc[0:2,'categ':'m'].plot(kind='bar');`. Although I'm not sure if bar plot is appropriate for your data as `f` has very small values for two of the categories.

Comment: Oh there is a mistake in the table I posted... Anyway I used df.iloc[0:3,0:2].plot(kind='bar'). Thanks for the help